# upsert in psql with more than one confliclt pk and unique

Tags: postgresql, upsert

will we i should use on conflict but th scenario is kinda weird

```sql
create table lookup(
  id GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(50) not null unique
);
```

2  conflicts may accrue

- dub pk
- name not unique

on conflict should add the next vacant id yet i may max() AND the unique constraint should be ignored

Comment: Looks to me the issue is you have duplicated PK's. Get rid of `id` and make `name` your PK.

Comment: Change the `id` column to` generated always as  identity`. This eliminates (with significant manual interpretation, or vastly too small a range between min value and max value) the possibility of duplicate value on that column. Thus eliminating you issue. Alternately just do as @AdrianKlaver has suggested .